# How to get value form QLineEdit() pyqt5 with pushing button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I have created the QLineEdit object and trying to get valuse from this widget, but at the end I've got an error:

```
qlineedit1 = QLineEdit()
qlineedit1.setFixedSize(btn_x_size, btn_y_size)
gridLayout.addWidget(qlineedit1, i, j)        
value = range_btn.clicked.connect(self.get_value(qlineedit1))

@pyqtSlot()
def get_text(self, obj):
    textboxValue = obj.text()
    return textboxValue
```

---

```
    text1 = range_btn.clicked.connect(self.get_text(qlineedit1))
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are the following:

- To the `connect()` method you must put the name of the function, not the evaluated function.
- the connection does not return anything, so value will always be None.

The `GUI`s work asynchronously because they want to obtain the data in the connection is not valid, you must obtain it in the slot.

if you want to pass additional parameters you could use the lambda function:

```
    qlineedit1 = QLineEdit()
    qlineedit1.setFixedSize(btn_x_size, btn_y_size)
    gridLayout.addWidget(qlineedit1, i, j)        
    range_btn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, obj=qlineedit1 : self.get_value(obj))

@pyqtSlot()
def get_text(self, obj):
    textboxValue = obj.text()
    print(textboxValue)
```